# Lock a particular method in java

Tags: java, ajax, concurrency

In my java webappication, there is an action which updates the order object and saves it in DB through ajax call(POST request).

Method saveOrder() performs this action,
if multiple users perform the same action, there should be lock on this method, so that the write transaction is performed with the latest data.

The class file code is as follows

```
public class OrderLoader extends JSONProcessSimple {

@override
public JSONObject exec(JSONObject jsonsent) throws JSONException, ServletException {
  JSONObject result = this.saveOrder(array);
  return result;
}

public JSONObject saveOrder(JSONArray jsonarray) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        //Write operation on DB
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Is it possible through synchronized approach, please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us more of your environment? Which kind of server are you using?

Comment: we are using a tomcat6 server, environment is servlet based with Hibernate ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization allone would not do the job since you'd block until the *first* request is saved and then you'd still have to check whether the other orders are newer or not.

As the others already stated, there's no easy solution and it would depend on your architecturea and environment.

You might want to try some optimitistic locking approach, i.e. each update checks a version column and increments it if the version matches. Something like `... SET version = x + 1 WHERE version = x`  and then you check whether columns have been updated or not.

That would not get the latest order to be saved but would prevent lost updates. You could, however, adapt that approach to only update the database whenever you have newer data (maybe based on some date and then use `WHERE date > x`).

**EDIT**:

Since you're using Hibernate, I'd look into Hibernate's optimistic locking. That would at least handle concurrent edits since only the first one would succeed. If non-concurrent edits result in OptimisticLockExceptions you are probably missing a (re)read somewhere.

With concurrent edit I mean user A reads the object, changes it and then triggers the write. In between user B has also read the object and triggers a write later. The writes are not concurrent but user B didn't see the changes of user A and thus might result in lost updates.

In your case it would depend on what operations are done on an order. In some cases you might safely reread the order just before persisting the changes (e.g. when adding positions, it might even be ok to do so when deleting them - if the position doesn't exist you just do nothing) while in other cases you might want to report the concurrent edit (e.g. when two users edit the quantity of the same position, the order header etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the architecture of your application (does it run in mutiple parallel instances in a clustered environment?), there is no simple solution; if it is executed in only one VM, `synchronized` could be an approach. Also, have a look at the [java.util.concurrent.lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) package.

For a more sophisticated, distributed approach, you could implement a DB-based lock.

Comment: It runs on a single instance. What is the difference between  synchronized &  java.util.concurrent.lock

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to check your database `isolation` and your SQL.  Perhaps you need a SERIALZIABLE connection or a transaction manager.  That's server side.

It's easy to add a `synchronized` keyword, but I think it's more than that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your method updates order for different users then you dont need to have any synchronization as every thread hitting the method will have its own copy, thus its not a concern.

But if all users  are acting on same data, you can use write to db in begintransaction and endtransaction. This should make concurrent writes threadsafe.

Comment: all users act on the same data and between each write operation the object must be updated.